# CAN we run ETL jobs on AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, etl, amazon-efs

I would like to know if we can run ETL jobs on EFS mount files..
if so how? is it using Hive or anyother service?
Our target is to reduce all the files in one mount point to one file...and store that one file in s3 for better processing

Answer (score 1):

EFS in itself does not inherently have a particular data warehouse product included. For data warehousing and ETL you can choose what you want to use that operates in the AWS environment.

On to your problem:
You want to concatenate or in some way combine all of the files currently in your EFS mount into a single file and store that in S3, if I understand it correctly.

You do not mention what type of data you have or what type of files you want to combine.  That makes a huge difference in how you would do this. So I will have to give general suggestions. If you have different types of data, SQL tables from different databases, documents, non-sql data; then you need to determine how to combine that data. For that you would be looking at a data integration solution that can accommodate raw data.

Amazon has a few different products that may assist the process such as Redshift, Athena, Snowflake and their ETL solution Glue.  Adding products depends on your company's needs and budget.

So, a more flexible data integration approach would be to use ELT (extract, load, transform) instead of ETL. Basically you would create an appropriate file over on your S3 instance. Then you would extract each file on EFS one at a time and load them into your S3 file. Then when you query the data in your S3 file you would perform any transformations needed before seeing the query results. Here's an article that explains the differences in more detail: https://blog.panoply.io/etl-vs-elt-the-difference-is-in-the-how.

There are some vendors supporting the ELT process such as Talend, Hadoop/Hive/Spark, Terradata and Informatica should you want to investigate options.